# className returns undefined with Mocha Enzyme & React CSS Modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, css-modules

I believe what I am trying to achieve has been done many times, but I can't manage it.

I would just like to be able to test if an element has a certain class on a certain element.

**Splash**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Logo from '../shared/logo/index';
import * as styles from './style.css';

class Splash extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className={styles.indexAppContent}>
        <NavLink to="/home"  className={styles.index}>
          <Logo />
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Splash;
```

**style.css**

```
.index {
  div {
    color: #FFF;
    //font-size: 8rem;
  }
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%,0);
}

.indexAppContent {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
```

However this is the output:

```
{ className: undefined,
  children: 
   { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
     type: { [Function: NavLink] propTypes: [Object], defaultProps: [Object] },
     key: null,
     ref: null,
     props: 
      { to: '/home',
        className: undefined,
        children: [Object],
        activeClassName: 'active',
        ariaCurrent: 'true' },
     _owner: null,
     _store: {} } }
```

**Splash**

```
/* eslint-disable object-property-newline */
import React from 'react';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

//Splash
import Splash from '../../../src/components/Splash';
import * as styles from '../../../src/components/Splash/style.css';

//logo
import Logo from '../../../src/components/shared/logo';


describe('<Splash />', () => {

  const wrapperSplash = shallow(<Splash/>);
  const wrapperNavLink = shallow(<NavLink />);
  const wrapperLogo = shallow(<Logo />);

  it('must be defined', () => {
    expect(wrapperSplash).to.be.defined;
  });

  it('should have one logo', () => {
    expect(wrapperSplash.find(Logo)).to.have.length(1);
  })

  it('should have className', () => {
    expect(wrapperSplash.first().prop('className'))
      .to.contain('indexAppContent');
  })

  it('Logo links to Home', () => {
    expect(wrapperSplash.find(NavLink).first().props().to)
      .equals('/Home');
  })

});
```

**Test**

```
/* eslint-disable object-property-newline */
import React from 'react';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

  it('should have className', () => {
    console.info(wrapperSplash.first().props());
    expect(wrapperSplash.first().prop('className'))
      .to.contain('indexAppContent');
  })
```

**Test Helper**

```
import path from 'path';
import csshook from 'css-modules-require-hook/preset' // import hook before routes
import routes from '/shared/views/routes'
import requireHacker from 'require-hacker';
import sass from 'node-sass';
import {jsdom} from 'jsdom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();

hook({
  extensions: ['.css'],
  generateScopedName: '[local]',
  preprocessCss: (data, filename) =>
    sass.renderSync({
      data,
      file: filename,
      importer: (url) => {
        if (url.indexOf('~') === 0) {
          const node_modules_path = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..', 'node_modules');

          return {
            file: path.join(node_modules_path, url.replace('~', ''))
          };
        }

        return {file: url};
      }
    }).css
});

const fakeComponentString = `
  module.exports = require('react').createClass({
    render() {
      return null;
    }
  });
`;

requireHacker.hook('svg', () => fakeComponentString);

// jsdom
const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];


global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

Comment: And `wrapperSplash` would be....?

Comment: Sorry guys, was just trying to make it smaller. I've updated it now

Comment: and where are you providing the `className` prop here? `const wrapperSplash = shallow(<Splash/>);` shouldnt it be `const wrapperSplash = shallow(<Splash className="something"/>);`?

Comment: lol updated again, I actually thought I had put that in

Comment: @Sag1v the prop should be coming from the component added to the test with `import Splash from '../../../src/components/Splash';` which is the component itselfs

Comment: but still, you are not passing any props. i think you really wanted to check the existing of a certain class value but in the child (or root element) of this component. see my answer with an example code

Answer (score 1):

You are checking a `prop` of that component and not the existence of a `class` in the root node that was rendered by this component.
Obviously you are not passing this prop.
You set the class on the root element of this component, thus you should check for nested element that hold this class **value** in the `dom` and not the attribute (prop) `className`
You can do it with this syntax for example:

```
 it('should have class of indexAppContent', () => {
    expect(wrapperSplash.find('.indexAppContent')).to.have.length(1);
  })
```

Comment: I see what you mean, the problem is that with css modules, the class is never output as what the style is. So the rendered class will never actually be `.indexAppContent`. I think this is really what is going on

Comment: would it be `index-appContent`? (cammelCase attribute in css modules)

Comment: It renders to `src-components-Splash-___style__indexAppContent___2gYy0` So pretty random, I believe it takes the days dateTime as well